# WPF - setting properties to themselves fails to fire changed event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties, inotifypropertychanged

Here's a curious piece of behaviour. We recently built some code in a WPF MVVM application that looked a bit like this:

```
foreach (var mA in Preferences.Where(itm => itm.Preference == "Y"))
{
    Member m = _members.FirstOrDefault(itm => itm.MemberID == mA.MemberAvertedID);
    if (m != null)
    {
        m.Selected = true;
    }
}

Members = _members;
```

So, FirstOrDefault fetches a reference to a Member, which is updated. Members and _members are effectively the same - the former is a property, wrapping the latter as a private variable, with an event fire:

```
public ObservableCollection<Member> Members
{
    get
    {return _members;}

    set
    {
            _members = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Members");
    }
}
```

The purpose of setting Members to _members was simply to get the event to fire - but it didn't work. As you stepped through, the OnPropertyChanged event fired, but the application didn't respond. This, however, does work:

```
foreach (var mA in Preferences.Where(itm => itm.Preference == "Y"))
{
    Members m = _members.FirstOrDefault(itm => itm.MemberID == mA.MemberAvertedID);
    if (m != null)
    {
        mtc.Selected = true;
    }
}

var mem = new ObservableCollection<Members>(_members);
Members = mem;
```

I'm assuming that what's going on here is that because setting Members to _members is effectively the property setting itself, the code "presumes" that nothing has changed, and skips the event. But I'm not really satisfied with that explanation. Can anyone elucidate further as to what's going on here?

Comment: Is `MembersToCount` another property? Shouldn't you also/instead raise property changed event for `Members` property?

Comment: `MembersToCount` what is it? can you show your code for that property?

Comment: ..also, is there a typo in the last sample? Assigning `OC<MembersToCount>` to the Members variable typed as `OC<Member>` will surely result in a compile error

Comment: Sorry, sorry, terrible copy & paste job. Hopefully makes more sense now. Apologies for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `Member` class.

Comment: @MattThrower it does not work because it still checks if value changed before UI refresh. If you want to do it this way you can set it to null first and then to `_members`

Comment: @Bolu it's in the base class.

Comment: @dkozl I guessed it was something like this, but where is this behaviour explained/described/documented? It's not what I expected.

Comment: If you have done that, then your `Select` property should `RaisePropertyChanged` by itself, so that your UI will get notified and you don't need to do `Members = _members;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings to ObservableCollections will not rebind the list unless the collection reference differs, hence the last piece of code is working. That said, unless you are actually adding or removing items from the underlying `_members` list you shouldn't have to rebind the whole list.

So (I assume) if your goal is to refresh the state of the Selected Member, you are probably lacking a `OnPropertyChanged("Selected")` raised from within the `Selected` property.

In summary: the property that is changing must be named in the PropertyChanged event. And the event must come from the object that owns the property. In this case, notifying WPF of a change to the `Selected` property requires raising the event on the `Member` instance.

Comment: Sorry - you're quite right but I made some terrible typos simplifying the code for the example. We're raising the right property in the actual production code.

Comment: Great, thanks. I didn't realise you could raise events on properties of properties!

Comment: Indeed. I was just waiting to see if anyone else chipped in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63784/discussion-between-peter-lillevold-and-matt-thrower).